# Inserting an image attachment into an NSMutableAttributedString on macOS with Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsimage, nstextattachment

I'd like to insert an image attachment into an `NSMutableAttributedString` on `macOS`. I've seen how this can work on `iOS`, but I'm not having much luck on `macOS`. On `iOS`, it can look like this:

```
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some great text")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "pic.png")
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
string.append(imageString)
```

On `macOS`, I'm trying this:

```
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "yeah yeah yeah")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: "<absolutePathTo>/pic.png")
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
string.append(imageString)
```

I expect the result to look like this:

```
NSAttachment = "<NSTextAttachment: 0x6000000e3b00> \"pic.png\""
```

But, the result is just an `NSTextAttachment` without a path:

```
NSAttachment = "<NSTextAttachment: 0x6040000e4700>"
```

`FileManager` says my png exists, given my path.

Comment: Does `NSImage(contentsOfFile: "<absolutePathTo>/pic.png")` return an image?

Comment: It's returning nil. Not sure why.

Comment: This is the issue and this has nothing to do with `NSMutableAttributedString`. Is the image inside the app bundle? Is App Sandbox switched on?

Comment: The image is outside of the app bundle. The App Sandbox is on, User Selected File is set to Read/Write.

Comment: I moved the image into my Downloads directory and updated entitlements to allow read/write from Downloads. The code works now. Guess I need to read up on sandboxing (I'm new to XCode). Thanks Willeke.